# Converting RGB images to LAB using scikit-image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to convert an RGB image into the LAB color space using skimage, but the result seems to be just noise. The same operation using opencv seems to work.

```
cat = io.imread('https://poopr.org/images/2017/08/22/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg')
cat_sk_image_lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(cat)
plt.imshow(cat_sk_image_lab)
cat_cv_lab = cv2.cvtColor(cat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
plt.imshow(cat_cv_lab)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the following in this question: If `cat` is an RGB image as the use of both `io.imread` and `skimage.color.rgb2lab` seem to suggest, why applying `cv2.cvtColor` with the option `COLOR_BGR2LAB`? Why not `COLOR_RGB2LAB`?

Comment: my mistake. It should have been RGB2LAB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The display issues are due to the ranges of Lab values which are: L (0-100), a (-128-127), b (-128-127).  This really should be documented--[our mistake](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1185).

To display a Lab picture, you can rescale the various bands to the desired range (0-1):

```
lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(cat)
lab_scaled = (lab + [0, 128, 128]) / [100, 255, 255]
```

[image: LAB Cat]

The [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_lab) describe doing exactly this conversion for you, *if* using 8-bit images.